# Angulartics: Google Analytics track full URI including anchor

Tags: cordova, angular, google-analytics

I am using Angulartics and Angulartics Google Analytics [1] to track user flow in an angular page. Tracking events works well. Also tracking pageviews is automatic and works. **However in Google Analytics dashboard I can not see the anchor part of the url.**

The tracking requests look like this:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
v=1&_v=j51&a=333486222&t=screenview&_s=7&
cd=%2Findex.html%23%2Fsign-in&
dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Findex.html&
ul=de&de=UTF-8&
dt=Treat&
sd=24-bit&sr=1918x941&
vp=1918x845&je=0&
fl=25.0%20r0&an=Treats&_u=SACAAMABO~&jid=&
gjid=&cid=1883662174.1492999789&
uid=Mark-user&tid=UA-9675XXXX-1&z=124537179
```

Notice how the `cd=%2Findex.html%23%2Fsign-in` includes `#sign-in` part of the URI,
but the important `dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Findex.html` does not.

My app.js looks like this:

```
... }).config(function ($analyticsProvider) {
$analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true); /*Records pages that don't use $state or $route*/
$analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true);  /*Records full path*/
$analyticsProvider.virtualPageviews(true);
});
;
```

How can I track the full URI including the anchor for pageviews with Angulartics without resorting to manual trigger-code?

[1] https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics

[2] https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#location

Comment: did you looked at this link - http://mediacause.org/track-anchor-tags-google-analytics-2/

Comment: did u tried it?

Comment: Dear Gandhi, the link you provided does not use Angulartics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did work arround it by disabling the built-in page-views and tracking in the stateChangeSuccess event handler like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', ... ,'angulartics',
    'angulartics.google.analytics',
    'angulartics.google.analytics.cordova','angulartics.mixpanel'])

.run(function($rootScope, $state, $analytics, $location){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

    // we do not use Angulartics virtual pageviews, instead we track them "manually" here because of
    // https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics/issues/550
    // also we track pageviews as events with the pageview path as event name to use the low cost plan of https://mixpanel.com/pricing/

    var currentPath =  $location.path();
    $analytics.pageTrack(currentPath);
    $analytics.eventTrack(currentPath, {category: 'pageview', label: 'pageview'});
  });
});
```

The point is to call `$analytics.pageTrack` with `location.path`.
Works quite well! I also reported a bug on the project website.

Comment: Backlink to upstream issue https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics/issues/550 But actual working hack is here on stack overflow.